# Fourier transform involving a delta function

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

For ease let us suppose that I am trying to transform the function $f(t)=\delta(a^2 -t^2)$. Therefore the Fourier transform is given by
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(a^2 -t^2)\exp(-i\omega t)\,dt.$$

My question is how to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-i\omega t)\,dt$, and how it relates to the delta function? I know that the Fourier transform of $\delta(t)$ is unity, but how does this change when considering  $ \delta(a^2 -t^2)$ ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Neither of the integrals here exist classically.  To get a sensible answer, you need to consider this problem in the sense of tempered distributions.

Comment: please see edit

Comment: What is a delta function ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html Question has been edited so it is no longer a duplicate

Comment: Why not use the method of Gaussian integrals? They usually work in such situations...